# how to check wds service is running or not

Tags: windows, service, active-directory, domaincontroller, wds

Can I please know how to check WDS service is running or not?

After patching, WDS service is disabled. Server asked for a reboot to start WDS. Can I know how to check WDS is running or not?

Answer (score 0):

First solution:

1. Go to the services page (Windows Key + R > type services.msc)
2. Search for **Windows Deployment Services Server**
3. Check if the status is **Running**

Second solution:

1. Start the commandline: Windows Key + R > CMD
2. Type **net start**
3. Check if **Windows Deployment Services Server** is listed

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically in PowerShell,

```
(Get-Service -Name "WDSServer").Status
```

To do the same remotely,

```
(Get-Service -ComputerName <computer name> -Name "WDSServer").Status
```